# How to add custom property (with inserted controls) in QtTreePropertyBrowser

Tags: c++, qt5

I would like to add custom property with inserted controls in QtTreePorpertyBrowser
Here is a sample snapshot for my requirement:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I straight away lifted below piece of code from (not tested).

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5256485/QtTreePropertyBrowser-vs-PropertyGrid-Application

The link may break in future, so copied below snippet. The code is bit straight forward.

```
QtVariantPropertyManager *variantManager = new QtVariantPropertyManager;
QtTreePropertyBrowser browser;
browser.setFactoryForManager(variantManager, new QtVariantEditorFactory);
QtVariantProperty *p = variantManager->addProperty(QVariant::Int, "Property1");
browser.addProperty(p);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I already have this code. It is mostly based on adding basic property types and to manage data in the QtTreePropertyBrowser.
What I would like is to create new property type with custom buttons within its rect (as shown in the snapshot).